# SmartyStreets jQuery.liveaddress plugin, how to unbind events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, smartystreets

I'm using smarty streets jquery.liveaddress plugin in an angular single page app.  I need to unbind all of the event listeners from the liveaddress instance when I transition to next page. Right now, if I come back to the page, all events are fired twice, then the next time on page, three times.

I've tried everything i can think of. My last solution was to unbind all of the event names from the $(document) because it looks like that is where the plugin is attaching all of the events to. but even that didn't work.

```
jQuery(document).unbind("AddressChanged");
        jQuery(document).unbind("AutocompleteUsed");
        jQuery(document).unbind("VerificationInvoked");
        jQuery(document).unbind("RequestSubmitted");
        jQuery(document).unbind("ResponseReceived");
        jQuery(document).unbind("RequestTimedOut");
        jQuery(document).unbind("AddressWasValid");
        jQuery(document).unbind("AddressWasAmbiguous");
        jQuery(document).unbind("AddressWasInvalid");
        jQuery(document).unbind("AddressWasMissingSecondary");
        jQuery(document).unbind("OriginalInputSelected");
        jQuery(document).unbind("UsedSuggestedAddress");
        jQuery(document).unbind("InvalidAddressRejected");
        jQuery(document).unbind("AddressAccepted");
        jQuery(document).unbind("Completed");
```

Comment: I noticed that in this list of unbind calls you missed "AutocompleteInvoked" and "AutocompleteReceived". Calling unbind does indeed detach the events.

Answer (score 1):

Ok for anyone trying to implement SmartyStreets jquery.liveaddress plugin in an angular application.

The trick was to not register anonymous event handlers.

In my case I was instantiating SmartyStreets in a directive, so put all the eventHandlers on scope and call liveAddress.deactivate() upon $destroy. No more duplicate events.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, event handler functions are stored in an array. Therefore, `unbind()` function looks just for the function in the aforementioned array. It further means that you can only `unbind()` event handlers which are already added with `bind()`.

Check out jQuery documentation on [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)